# Get index element of array by value

Tags: php, arrays

I have to get index element of array by value.

Suppose i have bellow snippet array.

```
Array ( [2671] => 24 [3149] => 1 [3711] => 2 [3695] => 16
 [3209] => 53 [3638] => 16 [3671] => 22 [3235] => 19 
[3773] => 10 [348] => 1 [3387] => 2 [3787] => 1 [3693] => 1
 [3248] => 28 [3816] => 2 [3060] => 3 [3200] => 2 [3741] => 2 
[3676] => 26 [3855] => 3 [3196] => 4 [3030] => 1 )
```

And i am getting highest 3 values from this array as bellow output.

```
Top value 53
Top value 28
Top value 26
```

So now i want get the element for value `53` is `[3209]` and for other values also like

```
28 is [3248]
26 is [3676]
```

How do get this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) would help. `array_search()` returns the `index` for the searched value.

```
echo '53 is [' . array_search(53, $array) . ']';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

`$key = array_search('28', $array);` // it will return the value

Answer (score 0):

use array_flip() as follows

```
$input = array(2671=>24, 3248=>28, 3676=>26);
$flipped = array_flip($input);
$result = $flipped[28];
```